# Change react navigation drawer stack based on auth. React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Im working on an app in which user registration is not required. That means that the users can access the app content even if they havent registered. I have a drawer navigator like this photo below:
[image]

The code for the stack navigator :

```
function AppStack(props) {
  const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <><Drawer.Navigator
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      drawerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: nowTheme.COLORS.PRIMARY,
        width: width * 0.65,

      }}
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintcolor: nowTheme.COLORS.WHITE,
        inactiveTintColor: nowTheme.COLORS.WHITE,
        activeBackgroundColor: "transparent",
        itemStyle: {
          width: width * 0.75 ,
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          paddingVertical: 16,
          paddingHorizonal: 12,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          overflow: "hidden"
        },
        labelStyle: {
          fontSize: 18,
          marginLeft: 12,
          fontWeight: "normal"
        }
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home"
    >
      
      <Drawer.Screen name={t('Home')} component={HomeStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name={t('News')} component={ArticlesStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name={t('Profile')} component={ProfileStack} />
       <Drawer.Screen name={t('Register')} component={Register}/>
      <Drawer.Screen name={t('Settings')} component={SettingsStack} />
      
      <Drawer.Screen name={t('Start Evaluation')} component={EvaluationsStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>

    </>
  );
}
```

What i want to achieve is that the Register to show only when the user is not registered and logout to show when the user registers. Any ideas for that?

Here is my auth context code:

```
import createDataContext from "./createDataContext";
import authApi from "../../api/authApi";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import * as RootNavigation from '../../auth/navigationRef';



const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add_error':
      return {...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
    case 'signup' :
      return  {errorMessage: '', token: action.payload };
    case "signin":
      return { errorMessage: "", token: action.payload };
    case 'clear_error_message':
      return {...state, errorMessage: ''};
    case 'signout': 
      return {token: null, errorMessage: ''}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const tryLocalSignin = dispatch => async () => {
  const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    dispatch({ type: 'signin', payload: token  });
    RootNavigation.navigate('App');
  } else {
    RootNavigation.navigate('Register');
  }
}

const clearErrorMessage = dispatch => () => {
  dispatch({type: 'clear_error_message'});
}

const signup = dispatch => async ({email, password, name}) => {
    try {
      const response = await authApi.post('/signup', {email, password, name});
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
      dispatch({ type: 'signup', payload: response.data.token});

      RootNavigation.navigate('Onboarding');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      dispatch({type: 'add_error', payload: 'Something went wrong with sign up'})
    }
  };


const signin = dispatch => async ({email, password}) => {
  try {
     const response = await authApi.post('/signin', {email, password});
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
     dispatch({type: 'signin', payload: response.data.token});
     RootNavigation.navigate('App');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    dispatch({
      type: 'add_error',
      payload: 'Something went wrong with sign in'
    })
  }
};

const signout = dispatch => async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
  dispatch({type: 'signout'});
  RootNavigation.navigate('Auth');
}

export const {Provider , Context} = createDataContext(
  authReducer,
  {signin, signup, signout, clearErrorMessage, tryLocalSignin, addQuest},
  {token: false, errorMessage: ''}

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for your token (or user data). Then use a selector to access the value (or whatever method you use to access data) and use conditional rendering:

```
const isLoggedIn = ...your logic to detect logged in status ...

{isLoggedIn 
  ? <Drawer.Screen name={t('Register')} component={Register}/> : 
  : <Drawer.Screen name={t('Logout')} component={Logout}/> }
```

Comment: What i did :
`const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
{state.token === false ?  <Drawer.Screen name={t('Register')} component={Register}/> : null  }
`
Now this works but still doesnt remove it since i have custom drawer component also, and it reads it from there

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group introduced in react-navigation v6 and you can create a custom context on top of your navigation and make a decision based on context values.

Link to doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/group/

For e.g

```
 const { isLoggedIn } = useContext(LogicContext); // any logic here

 return(
   <Drawer.Group>
       { isLoggedIn ? <Drawer.Screen name="LoggedInDrawer" component={LoggedInDrawer} /> :  <Drawer.Screen name="LoggedOutDrawer" component={LoggedOutDrawer} />
   </Drawer.Group>
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to use redux package in your project.
Just you can get registerration state by using useSelector of redux in the drawer component.